# 'int' object has no attribute called 'append'

Tags: python

while printing score its showing error

```
question1 = input("what is the capital of india ")
answer1 = "delhi"
print("")
question2 = input("what is the capital of telangana ")
answer2 = "hyderabad"
print("")
question3 = input("what is the capital of andhra pradesh ")
answer3 = "amaraavathi"
print("")
score = len([])
if question1 == answer1 :
        print("correct answer")
        print('')
else :
        print('wrong answer')
        print('')
if question2 == answer2 : 
        print("correct answer")
        print('')
else :
        print("wrong answer")
        print('')
if question3 == answer3 :
        print("correct answer")
        print('')
else :
        print("wrong answer")
        print('')
if question1 == answer1 :
        score.append(3)
else :
        score
if question2 == answer2 :
        score.append(2)
else :
        score
if question3 == answer3 :
        score.append(3)
else :
        score
print(score)
```

Comment: please format your code at least...

Comment: You have set score to be equal to `len([])`. So you've initialised it to equal `0`. You need to initialise it as just the list `score = []` and then call `print(len(score))` to achieve what you intended

Comment: Pease always give a proper error description, the full error traceback and explain what you have tried diagnosing and solving the problem.

Comment: yeah it worked thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `score = len([])` uses the `len` function, which returns the INTEGER (int) length of the list specified. In python, integers cannot be appended to, like you are trying to do when you try to append the score at the end. Perhaps what you were intending to do was add to the score, for which the syntax is `score = score + 1` and the shorthand version is `score += 1`